# Product image upload button not shown in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on magento 1.9 but product image upload button not shown up, i solved that issue by changing upload_max_filesize=100M but after one day when i run it then the image upload button is not there.

Comment: Can you check it in google chrome?

Answer (score 2):

These buttons are coming from flash.So check your media folder on following location

design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media

if there is no media folder then copy from fresh magento

I hope this will solve your problem you can also go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022532/image-upload-buttons-are-missing-in-magento-in-back-end) link.

Comment: I have checked this files are available.